# MongoDB - push and pull

Tags: mongodb, push, pull

Despite searching, I have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

I create a document and push this information inside

```
db.studenci.update({ "nr albumu" : 27 },
    { 
        "$push" : { 
            "oceny" : { "IABD": [3,2,3,4,5,7] }
        } 
    }
);
```

then I want to add following number (grade) into board by using this code

```
db.studenci.update({ "nr albumu" : 27 },
    { 
        "$push" : { 
            "oceny" : { "IABD": 7 }
        }
    }
);
```

Unfortunately I am adding the same subject again: IABD with another grade (number), I want to add following number to the created board.

Moreover, if I use pull I delete all subjects - IABD not only one number(grade).

How do I add an element to an existing subdocument array?

Comment: did you try `db.studenci.update({ "nr albumu" : 27 },
    { 
        "$push" : { 
            "oceny.0.IABD": 7 
        }
    }
);`?

Comment: Hi, I handled it on my own, but I guess your solution is also fine, I used the same code but without '0'. Thank you for help.

Comment: could you post the answer?